# $\mathbb{F}_q$-rational points on a variety defined by elementary symmetric polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field with $q$ elements, and $P(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n)$ a homogeneous polynomial in $n$ variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$. Suppose the degree of $P$ is relatively prime to $q$. Let $c$ be a nonzero element in $\mathbb{F}_q$. It is well known that $P(X,Y) - c$ is absolutely irreducible, i.e. it remains irreducible over the algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$ of $\mathbb{F}_q$.

For a given integer $k \geq 2$, let $P_1, \ldots, P_n$ be elementary symmetric polynomials in $X_1^k, \ldots, X_n^k$. Let $c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n$ be nonzero elements in $\mathbb{F}_q$. By Weil's theorem on number of solutions to equations over finite fields, it follows that each $P_i-c_i =0$  has a $\mathbb{F}_q$ rational point, so that the subvariety $V_i$ defined by each $P_i$ in $\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{F}}$ is nonempty. The question is whether the intersection of $V_i$ is nonempty, i.e. contains an $\mathbb{F}_{q}$-rational point, if $q$ is sufficiently large.

Comment: Have you heard of [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't missing a hypothesis in your first paragraph?  For example, $X^p + Y^p - 1 = (X + Y - 1)^p$ in $\mathbb F_p[X, Y]$.

Comment: @RaviFernando Thank you. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

The system $P_i=c_i,1\le i\le n,$ has a solution $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\Bbb{F}_p^n$ if and only if the polynomial
$$f(T)=T^n-c_1T^{n-1}+c_2T^{n-2}-\cdots+(-1)^nc_n$$
is a product of linear factors in $\Bbb{F}_p[T]$.

More often than not this is not the case. Consider the case $p=2$, $c_1=c_2=1$. The system
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}x_1+x_2&=&1,\\ x_1x_2&=&1.\end{array}\right.
$$
has no solutions in $\Bbb{F}_2$. This is because the first equation forces one of the $x_i$s to be equal to zero. Equivalently, the polynomial $f(T)=T^2+T+1$ has no roots in $\Bbb{F}_2$ (so cannot split into linear factors).

Do observe that the system has solutions over extension fields. If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the conjugate primitive third roots of unity in $\Bbb{F}_4$, they form a solution. Clearly the polynomial $f(T)$ splits into linear factors over an algebraic closure, and the intersection has a point with coordinates in an algebraic closure. The number of distinct points in the intersection depends on whether $f(T)$ has zeros  with multiplicity $>1$. If that is not the case, then there will be $n!$ distinct points gotten by permuting the $n$ zeros of $f(T)$ in $\overline{\Bbb{F}_p}$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Maybe I should edit the question by requiring $q$ to be sufficiently big.

Comment: @Vanya No matter how large $q$ is, there exists irreducible polynomials of any degree $n$ over $\Bbb{F}_q$. Basically becaus the field $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$ exists. Selecting the $c_i$ from such a polynomial, Vieta style, leads to the same situation.

Comment: However, if you restrict the $c_i$s to the prime field, and seek for solutions in $\Bbb{F}_{p^\ell}$, where $\ell$ is the least common multiple of $2,3,4,\ldots,n$, then you are guaranteed to have solutions (in $\Bbb{F}_{p^\ell}$).